# Local Time Code to Display on HTTPS

Tags: http, ssl, iframe, https, localtime

I recently moved to HTTPS. I am currently have a local time displayed on the site using the following code:

```
<iframe class="current-time" src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i35r7kr2/n47/tlau/fs12/fcfff/tct/pct/ahl/th2/ts1" frameborder="0" width="54" height="14" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

However now we are on HTTPS it does not show because its loaded from a http:// site so browsers don't display it.

Can someone advise a method of display our local time as http://free.timeanddate.com does not have an SSL certificate

ADDITON INFORMATION AS REQUESTED: 
When we load the site that is now secure the place where the time was once displayed is blank and the browser indicates that some insecure content has been blocked. See https://www.reeffree.com.au/ to see a secure site - the missing part is under "Call Us Mon-Fri 7am-9pm & Sat-Sun 8.30am-7pm Brisbane, Australia (AEST). At ReefFree it's currently " that can be found on the right top of the page below the slider. 
To see what it looked like before see the following link: http://www.extremefree.com.au/

Using this website you can see that it is the date and time script that is stated above that is causing the issue - I need to replace it with one with HTTPS: https://www.whynopadlock.com

Comment: give a little more details about your problem.

Comment: Not sure what extra detail you needed but I listed more info above

Comment: The easiest way is certainly not to rely on a third-party service and serve your own resource with the time (which you can embed directly, or with an iframe). Essentially, implement something on your server at `https://.../currentlocaltime` (for example) that calls some script to return the current time in the time zone you've configured. That shouldn't be too difficult and doable with almost any server side technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free service you're using supports HTTPS.  Simply go back to http://www.timeanddate.com/clocks/free.html and when you get to the "Get HTML" step, choose "Secure Web Page"  This will generate an `<iframe src="https://...`  Note the URL is `https` instead of `http`

Comment: Absolutely perfect - was changing it to https but didn't know it need the freesecure instead of free